# Where did the standard HTML window go on mailings with mosiaco installed?

Tags: mosaico

I'm testing an upgrade to 5.9.1 and have installed mosaico (versions listed below) and have a few issues with mailings.

Try to create a new mailing.  I don't see the standard HTML window with the wysiwyg editor.  I see one for Design which has the mosiaco templates in it.

If I select a standard (non-mosaico) template, I don't have anyway to see it nor edit it.

If I select a mosaico template, I get that editor and can edit it no problem.

Another issue that may be a clue, is if I hit preview HTML either from the main screen or from within the mosaico editor, nothing happens.  I get a db error with FK constraint on civicrm_mailing_trackable_url.  The sql is doing an insert and doesn't have the mail id.  It is only trying to insert url.

Clearly this works else where so I must have something basic wrong.

Versions:

civicerm 5.9.1

mosaico 2.0-beta4.1528762072

FlexMailer 1.0-beta1

Shoreditch 0.1-alpha30  I could never get this work.  It says it's optional so I skipped it.  In playing with this, the not working could be related.  It might work, in the mailing screens I wasn't getting the options for regular template and it looked like things weren't necessarily in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open the traditional UI for mailings, you can find this under `Mailings -> New Mailing(Traditional)` nagivation menu.

If you don't see that menu item, try updating mosaico ext to latest OR simply visit -

```
http://site-name/civicrm/a/#/mailing/new/traditional
```

Comment: I'm feeling stupid for not noticing that. Though, I'd say, the menus are inconsistent. The template option goes to std templates but the old mailing goes to the mosaico. There's a new menu for mosaico tempates and for the old std mailing.  IMHO, the mail mosaico should have been a new menu at the bottom along with the mosaico template new menu. Like types together.  Since this is an extension, it seems like since the old still exists, it should still be as it was and the new be added. Easier for existing users to understand especially since mosaico is so different and requires some training.

Answer (score 1):

Am I thinking you want to be able to tweak the HTML of a Mosaico mailing? I don't think there is a direct way of doing that. My workaround was to send the test mailing and then cut and paste the HTML into a traditional mailing in CiviCRM.